# ValueError: string keys in translate table must be of length 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал программу, которая превращает текст в азбуку Морзе.
Теперь захотел написать программу, которая уже текст в азбуке Морзе превращает в простой текст, но мне показывает ошибку:

> ```
> ValueError: string keys in translate table must be of length 1.
> ```

Вот код программы:

```
letter_to_morse = [ (".- ","A"),("-... ","B"),("-.-. ","C"),
                    ("-.. ","D"),(". ","E"),("..-. ","F"),
                    ("--. ","G"),(".... ","H"),(".. ","I"),
                    (".--- ","J"),("-.- ","K"),(".-.. ","L"),
                    ("-- ","M"),("-. ","N"),("--- ","O"),
                    (".--. ","P"),("--.- ","Q"),(".-. ","R"),
                    ("... ","S"),("- ","T"),("..- ","U"),
                    ("...- ","V"),(".-- ","W"),("-..- ","X"),
                    ("-.-- ","Y"),("--.. ","Z"),(" ","/")]


data = input("Decrypt: ")
print("=======================================")
print(data.upper().translate(str.maketrans(dict(letter_to_morse))))
```

Вот файл с программой: http://www.mediafire.com/file/k452fsd423fgbdi/Morse2.py/file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что строки ключей должны быть длины 1, вам нужен *другой* подход, *без использования метода `translate()`*.

Самый простой - прямо применить словарь сделанный из `letter_to_morse`:

```
In[2]: letter_to_morse = dict(letter_to_morse)
In[3]: data = input("Decrypt: ")
Decrypt: >? ... --- ...  .... . .-.. .--.
In[4]: "".join([letter_to_morse[c + " "] for c in data.split(" ")])
```

> ```
> Out[4]: 'SOS/HELP'
> ```

---

Чтобы включить возможность плохого ввода (например `--------`), вместо части

```
letter_to_morse[c + " "]
```

используйте метод `get()`:

```
letter_to_morse.get(c + " ", "#error#")
```

который возвращает его *второй* параметр (`"#error#"`), *когда первый не является ключом словаря.*

*Пример:*

```
In[5]: data = input("Decrypt: ")
Decrypt: >? ... -------- ...  .... . .-.. .--.
In[6]: "".join([latter_to_morse.get(c + " ", "#error#") for c in data.split(" ")])
```

> ```
> Out[6]: 'S#error#S/HELP'
> ```